Firebase sendPasswordResetEmail throws internal error with actionCodeSettings
I am using firebase in my react native project. For forget password I am using sendPasswordResetEmail. It works fine if i don't pass it actionCodeSettings but doesn't work with it. I want the user to return to app after resetting password if app exists, otherwise to web-app. I tried actionCodeSettings with only url but that also gives internal error even though the similar thing is working on my web-app with same url. I have verified the bundleId and package name, both are same as the ones on firebase apps.
It throws this error: [Error: [auth/internal-error] An internal error has occurred, please try again.]
const actionCodeSettings: FirebaseAuthTypes.ActionCodeSettings = {
      url: 'https://myurlhere.app/dashboard',
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      iOS: {
        bundleId: 'com.example.mobileapp',
      },
      android: {
        packageName: 'com.example.mobileapp',
        installApp: true,
        minimumVersion: '12',
      },
    };
auth()
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
      .then(() => {
        toaster.success('', 'Reset link sent successfully');
        navigation.goBack();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        toaster.error('', 'Something went wrong, make sure you have entered correct email.');
        console.log('Error sending reset link:', error);
      });

